# When is Azure (Java) BlobClient.uploadWithResponse ready with uploading?

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to upload an image to Azure and when it is properly uploaded I want to delete the original local image. To do so I need to know when the upload is succesful/ finished.

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.blobclient.uploadwithresponse?view=azure-java-stable) of `BlobClient.uploadWithResponse` mention it returns `Response<BlockBlobItem>`. Can I use this response to trigger a subsequent action/ method? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering Azure Storage is strongly consistent, you will get a successful response only when the blob is created. You can make use of the status code ([`201 - Created`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob#status-code)) to determine if the blob is created successfully or not.

To check the status code you can use [`getStatusCode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.core.http.rest.response.getstatuscode?view=azure-java-stable#com_azure_core_http_rest_Response_getStatusCode__) in [`Response`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.core.http.rest.response?view=azure-java-stable) object.

Comment: I see. And (not being that proficient in Java...) how would I proceed as this would be an async operation, how can I make it trigger another method call e.g.?

Comment: I'm also not proficient in Java (...but don't tell anyone :D). Please see sample here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/f21abcf8e63957fcd3f5a14654fa193c887734ba/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/src/samples/java/com/azure/storage/blob/BlobAsyncClientJavaDocCodeSnippets.java#L438. HTH.

Comment: I won't... I tried with `subscribe` is not recognized. Example applies to async version. I am working with synchronuous BlobClient. Any idea how to use the Response of `BlobClient.uploadWithResponse`?

Comment: @musicformellons You do not need to use `subscribe`: you are using the synchronous `BlobClient`. As a consequence, when the `uploadWithResponse` completes, the operation in Azure is finished as well, and you can safely remove your file from the local filesystem. Something like: `try {
  // Create BlobClient
  BlobClient client = ...;
  // Invoke uploadWithResponse. Consider use uploadFileWithResponse
  Response<BlockBlobItem> response = client.uploadWithResponse(...);
  if (response.getStatusCode() == 201) {
    // remove local file
  }
} catch (Throwable t) {
  // Handle error
}`